# How can I type Lithuanian stress characters (e.g., ą́, ė̃, m̃)?

Tags: keyboard, internationalization

This is an obscure use case, so I'm not surprised that there's nothing about this online. I already know how to type accent marks in general, and how to change keyboards. However, I was not able to find any way to type e.g. m̃ using the Lithuanian or ABC Extended keyboards. I thought option-N followed by M would work in ABC Extended, for instance, but it doesn't. Here is a complete list of the characters I would like to be able to type:

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.693.9500&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Note that only a subset of these pose an issue. For example, I can obviously type é, ȩ, and č in either of the keyboard layouts above.

Any advice is appreciated. I would prefer to not have to pick characters from the symbol selection table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For info on how to add combining diacritics to any character with ABC Extended, see this page

http://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/mac/codemacext/

For example, m̃ is made by typing m and then option-shift n. ė̃ is made by typing option w, e, then option-shift n.

The keystrokes for adding acute  ́ and grave  ̀ are option-shift e and option-shift `.

You might want to create a customized version of the Apple Lithuanian keyboard using [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to adding keys for the combining diacritics used to indicate stress.  [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7m2609bqlz1zyee/Lithuanian%20Stress.keylayout.zip?dl=0) is one you can try.

Comment: While that *does* work in TextEdit, the first example in brackets doesn't work in Safari (inserts HTML entity), and the example in editor requires key-strokes not explained at the link. Also, this is quite cumbersome to use from ABC-Ex. Are you aware of existing or howto custom 'keyboard layout' this from a more native layout?

Comment: Example editor is again *TextEdit* (maybe I have an extension/script active in *my* Safari, perhaps just disregard that part). // Your example m̃ & the linked howto gives: "Combing Diacritics: Type Letter first, then Code", you yourself have the letter in the middle of that sequence.

Comment: I tried that howto and typed starting with the letter 'e' to arrive at  ė̃, failing. As you now explain in the A one needs ' option w' *before* the actual letter e is hit. This complexity isn't covered in the howto? Haven't tried all cases and so am unsure on how to phrase that better for the more general issue. // If you have more cases covered: perhaps quote the whole howto here and complement the missing info?

Comment: Ah! This e example doesn't work for Lithuanian at all, *only* for ABCEx. Then, with e -> ė̃ I can follow either way with ABC, but not for a -> a˛ą ȧ˛a a. Culprit: in ABC I need to start with opt-m, then a & assisted by keyboard viewer 'opt-e' is highlighted as combining, shift-option-e is not, but that it is.  In Safari: correct sequence: 'ą́' but starting with a: 'a˛́'.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This does work, although it is slightly cumbersome. I guess my mistake was trying to type option-n before instead of shift-option-n afterwards (and the same for the other option combinations).

Should I mark this answer as accepted or wait for others?

Comment: @UserofDevice  This is how one does this kind of thing with ABC extended -- only certain combinations can be made via dead keys (option-n before) and the rest have to be done via combining diacritics (option-n after).  Combining diacritics may not look pretty with every font.   The standard Lithuanian layout cannot do combining diacritics, but creating a custom layout with just 3 extra characters would be pretty quick and simple too.

Comment: I guess option-backtick, option-n, and option-e as in ABC Extended would work. (Those mappings exist in the Lithuanian keyboard already, but they're not essential AFAICT. Option-backtick appears to do the same thing as normal backtick, option-e already adds an acute accent mark [but only to certain letters], and option-n does other stuff that's not important.) However, I don't really have any strong preference, if you have a better idea. :-)

Comment: @UserofDevice  Try this one    https://www.dropbox.com/s/7m2609bqlz1zyee/Lithuanian%20Stress.keylayout.zip?dl=0   Goes in Library/Keyboard Layouts. Logout/login.  Should be in Others category in sys prefs/keyboard/input sources/plus button

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly.